# Spring batch with multiple XML read write?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement to read and write the multiple xml files with spring batch..

Need to read the multiple xml files with parallel mode and update the some values in the jaxb objects(After validating the input data calling service). Then write in to different folder after changing the file name. Fine name pattern like below.
let say:
I have `111_in.xml, 222_in.xml` ... 
The output file names should be `111_out.xml, 222_out.xml`...
I have google this and all the examples are related to multiResource read and write it to one output.

Appreciate if some one can guide me how to do this with spring batch...

Comment: Have you tried writing the code? If yes, then have you faced any issues with the code? SO is not for completing the assignments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask